# The difference between vold and udevd

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb, udev

I knew that Android uses volume daemon instead of udevd.

Since both of these two daemons act similar as the following:

1. Use netlink socket to receive uevents sent from kernel.
2. Deals with file nodes for further processing.

I am not clear with the difference between these two different daemons.

Can someone provide feedback? It will be great with pros and cons.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at [vold source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/master) I can only tell that it's just a simple replacement for udevd.

You're right that vold is using netlink socket to receive uevents from kernel. But I'd say that it deals with **block** subsystem events rather than "file nodes" as you say.

In NetlinkHandler.cpp you can see the following:

```
void NetlinkHandler::onEvent(NetlinkEvent *evt) {
    VolumeManager *vm = VolumeManager::Instance();
    const char *subsys = evt->getSubsystem();

    if (!subsys) {
        SLOGW("No subsystem found in netlink event");
        return;
    }

    if (!strcmp(subsys, "block")) {
        vm->handleBlockEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Last lines just compare uevent subsystem string with "block". And that is the main difference from udevd a far as I can see because udevd handles **all** subsystems whereas vold is a simple daemon to handle block devices like memory cards.

Good presentation on vold: http://www.slideshare.net/wiliwe/android-storage-vold

**EDIT on subsystems**

A subsystem is a representation for a high-level portion of the kernel as a whole. Actually, subsystem is just a wrapper on kernel's `kset`. There is a nice writing about it in LDD3, chapter 14.1 - Kobjects, Ksets, and Subsystems.

For example, let's monitor events when I insert USB stick.

```
$ udevadm monitor -k
KERNEL[82215.299677] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[82215.299921] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[82215.300192] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10 (scsi)
KERNEL[82215.300226] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/scsi_host/host10 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[82216.339987] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[82216.340047] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[82216.340069] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/scsi_disk/10:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[82216.340088] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/scsi_device/10:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[82216.340302] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[82216.340445] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/bsg/10:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[82217.110295] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[82217.141629] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
```

To determine what is subsystem in this output let's look at udev code in [udevadm-monitor.c](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udevadm-monitor.c)

```
static void print_device(struct udev_device *device, const char *source, int prop)
{
        struct timespec ts;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
        printf("%-6s[%llu.%06u] %-8s %s (%s)\n",
               source,
               (unsigned long long) ts.tv_sec, (unsigned int) ts.tv_nsec/1000,
               udev_device_get_action(device),
               udev_device_get_devpath(device),
               udev_device_get_subsystem(device));
        if (prop) {
                struct udev_list_entry *list_entry;

                udev_list_entry_foreach(list_entry, udev_device_get_properties_list_entry(device))
                        printf("%s=%s\n",
                               udev_list_entry_get_name(list_entry),
                               udev_list_entry_get_value(list_entry));
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

In first printf, `udev_device_get_subsystem(device)` will output sybsystem in last field in parenthesis.

So for `udevadm monitor` output you can see the following subsystems:

- usb
- scsi
- scsi_host
- scsi_disk
- scsi_device
- scsi_generic
- bsg
- bdi
- block

udev will handle all of this events to create different entries under /dev, for example

- `/dev/disk/by-id/<entry>` will be created based on disk SCSI WWN
- `/dev/disk/by-path/<entry>` will be created based on PCI connections and SCSI host info.
- and so on

In contrast, **vold** only interested in uevents from **block** sybsystem, it does not care about scsi, usb or bdi stuff.

Comment: avd, would you mind to explain a bit more about the block and other subsystems? Provide some examples will be nice to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In android there is no udevd, it is called as ueventsd . Both Ueventsd and vold is present in android. Vold is for removalbale storages mainly sdcard, pendrive etc.